# Is there a way to auto check an input box when it's created?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I'm maintaining an old ASP Classic site that auto generates rows in a table. So when the input box for that row is generated, it's given an auto generated name. So I don't won't know the ID/name before hand.

If I throw the following code in the onmouseover event, it works. But I can't figure out how to get the code to run when the input control is created.

```
document.getElementsByName(this.name)[0].checked = true;
```

This is what the whole row looks like:

```
<td class="tabledatacell" valign="top" nowrap>  
   <input disabled class="mccheckbox" onloadstart="document.getElementsByName(this.name)[0].checked = true;" mcType="B" mcRequired="N" type="checkbox" value="ON" name="txtal1AutoAssignROW_ID">
</td>
```

I tried events like onload and onloadstart, but they won't fire. Even when it's just an alert.

Comment: Did you try just adding `checked="checked"` to the input ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm a dummy. I didn't even think about setting a default value -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it with HTML like this: (add `checked` attribute)

```
    <td class="tabledatacell" valign="top" nowrap>  
       <input disabled class="mccheckbox" mcType="B" mcRequired="N" type="checkbox" value="ON" name="txtal1AutoAssignROW_ID" checked>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `checked` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```